# Aggregate query on After Insert returns null

Tags: apex, trigger, aggregate

I am working on a class that will identify if an account has a primary contact when an contact is inserted or updated.trigger is on contact to fire on after update/After insert.

```
    private void FindMasterContact(List<Contact> ContactList)
    {
            Map<Id, Integer> AccPrimaryConsMaps = new Map<Id, Integer>();
            Set<Id> Accountids = new Set<Id>();

            for(Contact Con : ContactList)
            {
                Accountids.add(Con.AccountId);
            }

            List<AggregateResult> Aggregateoutput = [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) MasterConcounts from Contact WHERE AccountId IN : Accids AND Primary = true GROUP BY AccountId];


            for(AggregateResult Aggregatr : Aggregateoutput)
            {
                AccPrimaryConsMaps.put((Id)Aggregatr.get('AccountId'),(Integer)Aggregatr.get('MasterConcounts'));
            }


            for(Contact Con : ContactList)
            {
                 System.debug('Aggregate Output***'+ AccPrimaryConsMaps.get(Con.AccountId));
                if(AccPrimaryConsMaps.get(Con.AccountId) == null) {
                Con.Primary = true;
}
            }
    }
```

I Inserted 5 contacts(loaded in list) with the Same acccountId. The aggregate list returned empty on After Insert. But when i run an update on the same list( After update runs) I can see the Aggregate list is populated.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Output** :

```
(On After Insert)
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******null
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******null
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******null
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******null
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******null


(On After update)
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******5
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******5
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******5
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******5
|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Aggregate Output******5
```

Comment: how are you calling this from trigger` FindMasterContact(List<Contact> ContactList)` ?

Comment: i have a handler that calls the class - PrimaryContactHandler pch = new PrimaryContactHandler (); pch.FindMasterContact(ContactList). There is  more to the code if i don't find primary contact i mark the current record as primary( updated the OP). But aggregate query is returning empty on After Insert that's the challenge i am facing right now